# displaying *argv except the first argument

Tags: c

I'm new to C , here is a simple program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define str char *

int main(int k, const str argv[]) {
    while(* argv) puts(* argv ++);
    return 0;
}
```

So when I type in shell, ./myprogramm somearg otherarg

I get:

myprogram
somearg
otherarg

What I would like to do is skip the first argument and have:
somearg
otherarg

**The important thing is that I want to keep the *argv implementation**

I know I could do something like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define str char *

int main(int k, const str argv[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while(i<k-1){
        puts(argv[++i]) ;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

**But I want to keep the *argv implementation**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you do *argv++; then use the while loop? (skipping the first value)

Comment: Nope, my array will go to far and I'll get "Segmentation fault
" error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most minimal change to the first version, you could use

```
while(*++argv) puts(*argv);
```

in your main loop. It skips argument "zero" right away. (Tested)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable that checks whether or not you are in the first iteration of the loop.

```
int main(int k, const str argv[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while(*argv) {
        if (i != 0) puts(*argv++);
        i = 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like my solution keeping *argv , don't you see any other possibility ? even a dirty one, working on *argv itself ? stuff like *argv=null idk ... You guessed it's for exercise purpose.. :)

Comment: no, it checks for the first argument and only prints the arguments if it isn't the first argument.

Comment: alexander solution seems the best, still upvoting your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int k, const str argv[]) {
int i = k-1;
while(i>0){
    puts(argv[i]) ;
i--;
}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: this is what I wrote with a regressive while so nope, but thanks for trying to help

Comment: Adding an explanation to code-only answers usually makes them more helpful to the community

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and it works. No seg faults..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define str char *
int main(int k, const str argv[]) {
    *argv++;
    while(* argv) puts(* argv ++);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: nope get this error :cx033.c: In function ‘main’:
cx033.c:5:2: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
  * argv++;
  ^

Comment: Ah, in that case Alexanders answer is the same except it won't throw that warning. (since it's used in the while loop)

Comment: I tried your code before you proposed it and I have a real error not a just a warnign I mean it's not working even if indeed I kinda don't get the difference it seems this not the same

Comment: Just changing that first `*argv++;` to `argv++;` should get rid of the warning... it's just complaining that you dereference argv and don't do anything with the result... but the increment is on `argv`, not `*argv` anyway.